# Double summation of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am interested in the following sum for a given value of n:

$ \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{y=1}^{n}x^y$

I can simplify this to

$ \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n} \frac{x^{n+1} - x}{x - 1}$

From here I can't see any way to further simplify this. Is there an exact value for this sum? If not, is there an algorithm to calculate it efficiently?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) might be of interest.

Comment: This is sequence A086787 at OEIS which seems to be extremely complex to put is a closed form.